# Method Invocation actionbar.somemethod() may produce java null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

In my application I want to customize my actionbar but when I try to do the same Java NullpointerException is thrown by my application.Also in my application I am using navigation drawer in which I have to add fragments to main activity so in some of my fragment I not want to show action bar but when I call actionbar.hide() it throws JNE. here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
Boolean flag = false;
ListView mDrawerList;
RelativeLayout mDrawerPane;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();
static GoogleMap mMap;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    if (findViewById(R.id.mainContent) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainContent, homefragment).commit();
        flag = true;
    }
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Profile",R.drawable.ace));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Book A Truck",R.drawable.ace));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("My Bookings",R.drawable.ace));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Farecards",R.drawable.ace));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Call Support",R.drawable.ace));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("About",R.drawable.ace));

    // DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    // Populate the Navigtion Drawer with options
    mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Drawer Item click listeners
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 4){
                String number = "tel:9643173925";
                Intent telephonecall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(number));
                startActivity(telephonecall);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
            } else if (position == 1 && flag) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
            } else {
                selectItemFromDrawer(position);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragmentClass = ProfileFragment.class;
            flag = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            flag = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentClass = MybookingFragment.class;
            flag =false;
            break;
        case 3:
            fragmentClass = FarecardFragment.class;
            flag = false;
            break;
        case 5:
            fragmentClass = AboutFragment.class;
            flag = false;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            flag = true;
            break;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String backstackname = fragmentClass.getName();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And my Manifest file code is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="in.moovo.route.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="in.moovo.route.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- <service -->
    <!-- android:name="in.moovo.MyGcmListenerService" -->
    <!-- android:exported="false" > -->
    <!-- <intent-filter> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> -->
    <!-- </intent-filter> -->
    <!-- </service> -->
    <!-- <service -->
    <!-- android:name="in.moovo.MyInstanceIDListenerService" -->
    <!-- android:exported="false"> -->
    <!-- <intent-filter> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/> -->
    <!-- </intent-filter> -->
    <!-- </service> -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Googlemap"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_googlemap" >

        <!-- <intent-filter> -->
        <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> -->


        <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
        <!-- </intent-filter> -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Confirm"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_confirm" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Moovo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_moovo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Erro log give this :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.moovo.route/in.moovo.route.Moovo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at in.moovo.route.Moovo.onCreate(Moovo.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
```

My style.xml file :

```
resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--Action bar style-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbartheme</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbartheme</item>
    <item name="height">50dp</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#a91c44</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">#a91c44</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Most likely, you are using appcompat and should be using `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: still not working, when I am using getSupportActionBar it says incompatible type error

Comment: you need to change the `import` from `android.app.ActionBar` to `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Comment: Still not working same problem :(

Comment: You edited your question. You are using the native `ActionBar` so `getActionBar()` is correct. What is line 41 in Moovo.java? I bet your `AppTheme` is an appcompat theme. You can try changing `extends Activity` to `extends ActionBarActivity` (then you would need to use `getSupportActionBar()`).

Comment: But with using getSupportActionBar() NPE is still thrown when actionBar.hide() or actionBar.show() methods is called. I have edited my question in which I give my style.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Your `Activity` (`Moovo`) inherits the application theme specified in your `AndroidManifest`. Your theme is a parent of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. This theme removes the native `android.app.ActionBar` which is why `getActionBar()` returns `null`.

You should do one of two things:

---

### First option:

Have your `Activity` class `Moovo` extend `AppCompatActivity` and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Your changes would look something like this:

```
...

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

...

public class Moovo extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        ...
```

---

### Second Option:

Do not use an AppCompat based theme. All AppCompat themes remove the native `ActionBar` and replace it with `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Still same problems after applying your all solution with actionbar.hide() and actionbar.show(). Can u give me any working code?

Comment: can you post what you updated? I'm pretty confident in my answer.

Comment: I have updated the mainactivity code please go through it